# map/fold operators (in c++)

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming

I am writing [library](http://volnitsky.com/project/ro/) which can do map/fold operations on ranges.  I need to do these with operators.  I am not very familiar with functional programming and I've tentatively selected `*` for map and `||` for fold.  So to find (brute force algorithm) maximum of  `cos(x)` in interval: `8 < x < 9`:

```
double maximum = ro::range(8, 9, 0.01) * std::cos  || std::max;
```

In above, `ro::range` can be replaced with any STL container.

I don't want to be different if there is any convention for map/fold operators. My question is:  is there a math notation or does any language uses operators for map/fold?

** EDIT **

For those who asked, below is small demo of what RO currently can do.  `scc` is small utility which can evaluate C++ snippets.

```
// Can print ranges, container, tuples, etc directly (vint is vector<int>) :
scc 'vint V{1,2,3};  V'
{1,2,3}

// Classic pipe. Alogorithms are from std::
scc 'vint{3,1,2,3} | sort | unique | reverse'
{3, 2, 1}

// Assign 42 to [2..5)
scc 'vint V=range(0,9);   range(V/2, V/5) = 42;  V'
{0, 1, 42, 42, 42, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}


// concatenate vector of strings ('add' is shotcut for std::plus<T>()):
scc 'vstr V{"aaa", "bb", "cccc"};  V || add'
aaabbcccc

// Total length of strings in vector of strings
scc 'vstr V{"aaa", "bb", "cccc"};  V * size ||  (_1+_2)'
9

// Assign to c-string, then append `"XYZ"` and then remove `"bc"` substring :
scc 'char s[99];  range(s) = "abc";  (range(s) << "XYZ") - "bc"'
aXYZ


// Remove non alpha-num characters and convert to upper case
scc '(range("abc-123, xyz/") | isalnum) * toupper'
ABC123XYZ


// Hide phone number:
scc "str S=\"John Q Public  (650)1234567\";  S|isdigit='X';  S"
John Q Public  (XXX)XXXXXXX
```

Comment: How would your fold operator work on empty ranges?

Comment: There is a proposed math notation called [Bananas](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.125) for folds. And there are Perl 6 [metaoperators](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/day-5-metaoperator/). Admittedly, both are not very suitable for C++, though.

Comment: @n.m -- It is currently undefined for empty ranges.  But I am thinking adding to folding functors special value `empty_value`, just for this case.  So `add` functor (similar to `std::plus<T>())  will have `empty_velaue==0`, and `mul==1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the languages I know, there is no standard way for folding. Scala uses operators `/:` and `:\` as well as metthod names, Lisp has `reduce`, Haskell has `foldl`.

`map` on the other hand is more common to find simply as `map` in all the languages I know.

Answer (score 12):

This is really more a comment than a true answer, but it's too long to fit in a comment.

At least if my memory for the terminology serves correctly, map is essentially `std::transform`, and fold is `std::accumulate`. Assuming that's correct, I think trying to write your own would be ill-advised at best.

If you want to use map/fold style semantics, you could do something like this:

```
std::transform(std::begin(sto), std::end(sto), ::cos);
double maximum = *std::max_element(std::begin(sto), std::end(sto));
```

Although `std::accumulate` is more like a general-purpose fold, `std::max_element` is basically a `fold(..., max);` If you prefer a single operation, you could do something like:

```
double maximum = *(std::max_element(std::begin(sto), std::end(sto),
    [](double a, double b) { return cos(a) < cos(b); });
```

I urge you to reconsider overloading operators for this purpose. Either example I've given above should be clear to almost any reasonable C++ programmer. The example you've given will be utterly opaque to most.

On a more general level, I'd urge extreme caution when overloading operators. Operator overloading is great when used correctly -- being able to overload operators for things like arbitrary precision integers, matrices, complex numbers, etc., renders code using those types *much* more readable and understandable than code without overloaded operators.

Unfortunately, when you use operators in unexpected ways, precisely the opposite is true -- and these uses are certainly *extremely* unexpected -- in fact, well into the range of "quite surprising". There might be question (but at least a little justification) if these operators were well understood in specific areas, but contrary to other uses in C++. In this case, however, you seem to be inventing a notation "out of whole cloth" -- I'm not aware of anybody using any operator C++ supports overloading to mean either fold or map (nor anything visually similar or analogous in any other way). In short, using overloading this way is a poor and unjustified idea.

Comment: +1, though I disagree with many points that you made. STO library is something opposite of "industrial strength".  It is born out of something like CodeJam library and need to jam  C++ verbosity into one-liner (for my other - SCC project). Expression can be  be x10 time shorter than using standard STL interface. BTW, your example is not equivalent. Your code needs to store elements of range, and my expression is not storing anything.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: Not really -- the examples I gave will accept any properly-functioning iterators. Yes, those typically iterate over a container, but no, that's not really a requirement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an implementation of `fold` in quasi-human-readable infix C++ syntax. Note that the code is not very robust and only serves to demonstrate the point. It is made to support the more usual 3-argument `fold` operators (the range, the binary operation, and the neutral element).

This is easily the funnies way to abuse (have you just said "rape"?) operator overloading, and one of the best ways to shoot yourself in the foot with a 900 pound artillery shell.

```
    enum { fold } fold_t;

template <typename Op>
struct fold_intermediate_1
{
    Op op;
    fold_intermediate_1 (Op op) : op(op) {}
};

template <typename Cont, typename Op, bool>
struct fold_intermediate_2
{
    const Cont& cont;
    Op op;
    fold_intermediate_2 (const Cont& cont, Op op) : cont(cont), op(op) {}
};

template <typename Op>
fold_intermediate_1<Op> operator/(fold_t, Op op)
{
    return fold_intermediate_1<Op>(op);
}

template <typename Cont, typename Op>
fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, true> operator<(const Cont& cont, fold_intermediate_1<Op> f)
{
    return fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, true>(cont, f.op);
}

template <typename Cont, typename Op, typename Init>
Init operator< (fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, true> f, Init init)
{
    return foldl_func(f.op, init, std::begin(f.cont), std::end(f.cont));
}

template <typename Cont, typename Op>
fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, false> operator>(const Cont& cont, fold_intermediate_1<Op> f)
{
    return fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, false>(cont, f.op);
}

template <typename Cont, typename Op, typename Init>
Init operator> (fold_intermediate_2<Cont, Op, false> f, Init init)
{
    return foldr_func(f.op, init, std::begin(f.cont), std::end(f.cont));
}
```

`foldr_func` and `foldl_func` (the actual algorithms of left and right folds) are defined elsewhere.

Use it like this:

```
foo myfunc(foo, foo);
container<foo> cont;
foo zero, acc;

acc = cont >fold/myfunc> zero; // right fold
acc = cont <fold/myfunc< zero; // left fold
```

The word `fold` is used as a kind of poor man's new reserved word here. One can define several variations of this syntax, including

```
<<fold/myfunc<< >>fold/myfunc>>
<foldl/myfunc> <foldr/myfunc>
|fold<myfunc| |fold>myfunc|
```

The inner operator must have the same or greater precedence as the outer one(s). It's the limitation of C++ grammar.

For `map`, only one intermediate is needed and the syntax could be e.g.

```
mapped = cont |map| myfunc;
```

Implementing it is a simple exercise.

Oh, and please don't use this syntax in production, unless you know very well what you are doing, and probably even if you do ;)